# Как сослаться на ресурс в классе

Tags: java, android

Есть класс `RadioPlayer`, который реализует класс для проигрывания и остановки плеера. Используется ExoPlayer. Как сослаться  в этом классе на `R.id.player`. У меня в этом классе в строке `RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);` ошибка компиляции. Можно отнаследовать класс от AppCompatActivity, но тогда у меня другая ошибка т.к. метод статический, то пишет что findViewById нельзя использовать в статик методах. А метод мне нужен статический, чтобы вызывать его в сервисе

```
public class RadioPlayer {

    static BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    static TrackSelector trackSelector;
    static SimpleExoPlayer player;
    static LoopingMediaSource loopingSource;
    public static SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

    public static void startPlayer(String url, Context context) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }

        Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector( videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, loadControl);
        RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(context);
        RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);

        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true); 
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus(); 

        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(url);


        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "caucasusradios"), bandwidthMeterA);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
        player.prepare(loopingSource);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                player.stop();
                player.prepare(loopingSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }
        });

    }

    public static void stopPlayer() {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Мне пришлось сделать SimpleExoPlayerView статическим и в классе PlayerActivity в методе onCreate сделать так

```
RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
```

но вроде нельзя делать ресурсы статическими. Поэтому хотелось бы сделать SimpleExoPlayerView и в классе RadioPlayer как-то сослаться на ресурс